# Android not showing programmatically created ImageView

Tags: android, layout, view, imageview, setcontentview

I am creating an ImageView in my project like this:

```
RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) ((Activity) GameGuessActivity.context).findViewById(R.id.layout);
ImageView img = new ImageView(GameGuessActivity.context);

img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
params.leftMargin = x;
params.topMargin = y;
root.addView(img, params);
```

But the Image is not displaying. I am creating the image after the setContentView(R.layout.layout) is being called, could that be the reason? If yes, how can I 'refresh' the layout to include the image but not change anything to existing Views?

Comment: Replace ImageView img = new ImageView(GameGuessActivity.context);
 by ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView); make sure you create this imgView in the layout. This shall do the job for you.

Comment: @iqbal I am not creating the Image in the layout first. They are only created by code because the amount of them created depends

Comment: Ok, then you can follow this link: http://www.eclpeople.com/how-do-i-add-an-imageview-to-the-root-layout-qq-AUvBUcbEivICeoL1jM-G.php

Comment: But this reloades the activity, including all the code going on there. I just want to update the view to include the created image, not reload the whole activity

Comment: How about using a layout inflater to create to first inflate your layout. Then you could add your imageView into this layout and finally you could call setContentView and pass this layout.

Comment: I am creating the ImageView after setContentView has been executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following **could** work:

```
View root = getLayoutInflater.inflate(your_layout, null);
ImageView img = new ImageView(GameGuessActivity.context);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
params.leftMargin = x;
params.topMargin = y;
root.addView(img, params);
setContentView(root);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use the `LayoutInflator` to create a view based on your layout template,
>   and then inject it into the view where you need it.

```
 LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

// fill in any details dynamically here
TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.a_text_view);
textView.setText("your text");

// insert into main view
ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.insert_point);
insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```